# Managing changes from different remote repositories

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I have just setup a LAMP stack application on the AWS EC2 instance for development purposes. I have also install Guy on the instance and setup a CodeCommit repo.

However, I have another gitlab repo where there are frequent changes. I used FTP initially to transfer files to the EC2 instance. My question would be how do I sync changes  such that the code on the EC2 instance and Gitlab is identical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+two+repositories